# Cutover: adjective, action noun, state - all the same?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, nouns

I'm a product Manager writing about a technological system in which a computer system is cutover (switched from one location to another).

Cutover is the action.

Is it also the state that the machine is in after the action is done?

Think of Delete and Deleted...

Comment: There is endless literature on fault tolerance, and I'm sure you could find a good glossary which would supply you with the official or at least best recognized terms.

Comment: Think of cut and cut....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *cutover* is the state after the action has been done. It's the same as the action because the past participle of the verb *cut* is the same: *cut*. If you separate *cut* from *over* (because this really is two words that have been joined into a single IT jargon word) it's easier to understand. Compare with *holdover* (another very common IT term in banking): The bank announces it will *holdover* some transactions; once this has been done, the transactions are in a *heldover* state - because the past participle of *hold* is *held*.